How to integrate and enable Pipeline in Open Web UI
I want to integrate and enable the pipeline text_to_sql_pipeline.py in Open Web UI. The code for text_to_sql_pipeline.py is available in https://github.com/open-webui/pipelines/blob/main/examples/pipelines/rag/text_to_sql_pipeline.py
Could you please guide me through step by step procedure to enable the pipeline in open web UI through Docker container?
Here is What I have done:

Executed the Open Web UI with Ollama using Docker container
Ran the pipeline container separately using

docker run -d -p 9099:9099 --add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway -v pipelines:/app/pipelines --name pipelines --restart always ghcr.io/open-webui/pipelines:main

Login to Open WebUI: In Open WebUI: Navigate to the Admin Panel > Settings > Connections > OpenAI API section.
Set the API URL to http://host.docker.internal:9099 and the API key to 0p3n-w3bu!.

Then in the pipeline section, I uploaded the text_to_sql_pipeline.py from my local computer. But I could not see Pipeline activated in open web UI. It shows : there are no Valves.

I also tried to mention the Github URL to the pipeline which is https://github.com/open-webui/pipelines/blob/main/examples/pipelines/rag/text_to_sql_pipeline.py But this also does not work.



Please provide me the solution to this. Let me know If I am missing any steps or am doing any error?
